# Spark Structured Streaming state management with RocksDB

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, rocksdb

For a particular use case we are using spark structured streaming, but the process is not efficient and stable. Aggregation stateful operation is the most time taking as well as memory crunching stage in the whole job. Spark Streaming provides an implementation of rocksDB to manage state. It helped us to gain some stability but added an overhead of time. So we are looking to optimise the rocksDB implementation. While exploring the logs we got to know that the **Memtable Hit** count is always zero and the **Block Cache** hit count is very low. It will be very helpful if someone can throw light on this.

RocksDB in itself provide various tuning parameters like **write_buffer_size**, **min_buffer_to_merge**. We tried to expose these parameters to spark. And then set the parameters value high in order to increase our chances of hitting memtable but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB is mostly a back up for state (other option is HDFS) or used during shuffle when local cache(memory)for a partition key is not within same executor.
You can check stateful operator metrics provided in spark ui to see how memory(cache) is being used before it hits rocksdb.

May be this below article can help on getting more info.
https://medium.com/@vndhya/stateful-processing-in-spark-structured-streaming-memory-aspects-964bc6414346.  (disclosure: its written by me)